# Apache web server on centos Redhat has a big loading time when i connect on website

Tags: php, apache, centos, webserver

I have a website on an apache server (centOS RedHat) and sometimes (random) when i try to connect on site i have to wait like 5-30 minutes before i can see the page.
I check the netstat and this is how it's look:
`tcp        0      0 site.example.com 1xx.xx.x.xxx:60971          ESTABLISHED`

I tried to search for problems, but i didn't find anything.
So, somebody had the same problem and can help with this problem
Thanks!.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general server tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you definitely need to look at your server configuration
Is server overloaded? At all, or in the moment of this website loading?
Don't you have MySQL slow queries in status output?
Is your site entirely static or you're using PHP?

Netstat is nothing to do about it, it only shows you that connection was established at all.

Did you look for apache logs for this website at all?
Are there any other sites on the server?
If you only face this issue with this one, you should take a look for the logs at first!

Take a look for your apache config too!
You can find some examples [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/lamp-package-setup.html).